# Error when building notepadqq from source code

Tags: linux, makefile

I went to the notepadqq github page and followed their specified steps. First I updated the required libraries, then I downloaded the git files. Then I ran this command `./configure --prefix /usr`. All went well until I tried to build it. All I did was run this command `make`. This is the output it gave me:

```
petar74@LVLH:~/bin/notepadqq$ make
cd src/ui/ && ( test -e Makefile || /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile /home/petar74/bin/notepadqq/src/ui/ui.pro PREFIX=/usr QMAKE_CXX=c++ 'QMAKE_CXXFLAGS= ' QMAKE_LFLAGS= 'LRELEASE=/usr/bin/qtchooser -run-tool=lrelease -qt=5' CONFIG+= ) && make -f Makefile 
Project MESSAGE: Release build
Updating '/home/petar74/bin/notepadqq/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_de.qm'...
    Generated 453 translation(s) (453 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/home/petar74/bin/notepadqq/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_es.qm'...
    Generated 454 translation(s) (454 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/home/petar74/bin/notepadqq/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_fr.qm'...
    Generated 345 translation(s) (345 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/home/petar74/bin/notepadqq/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_hu.qm'...
    Generated 454 translation(s) (454 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/home/petar74/bin/notepadqq/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_it.qm'...
    Generated 451 translation(s) (434 finished and 17 unfinished)
    Ignored 1 untranslated source text(s)
Updating '/home/petar74/bin/notepadqq/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_ja.qm'...
    Generated 447 translation(s) (447 finished and 0 unfinished)
    Ignored 5 untranslated source text(s)
Updating '/home/petar74/bin/notepadqq/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_pl.qm'...
    Generated 452 translation(s) (452 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/home/petar74/bin/notepadqq/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_pt.qm'...
    Generated 454 translation(s) (454 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/home/petar74/bin/notepadqq/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_ru.qm'...
    Generated 328 translation(s) (326 finished and 2 unfinished)
    Ignored 17 untranslated source text(s)
Updating '/home/petar74/bin/notepadqq/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_sl.qm'...
    Generated 345 translation(s) (345 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/home/petar74/bin/notepadqq/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_sv.qm'...
    Generated 359 translation(s) (359 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/home/petar74/bin/notepadqq/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_uk.qm'...
    Generated 453 translation(s) (453 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/home/petar74/bin/notepadqq/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_zh.qm'...
    Generated 448 translation(s) (448 finished and 0 unfinished)
Project ERROR: uchardet development package not found
make: *** [Makefile:46: sub-src-ui-make_first] Error 3
```

I don't want to install notepadqq using the snapd, I want to build it and I'm not that experienced using make. So please help me if you can. It would be useful to know where did I make a mistake and how to fix this. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for troubling everyone. I found the answer and it was that I didn't have installed `pkg-config` package the is used in this command `./configure --prefix /usr`. So I just installed it and the notepad is compiling while I'm writing this so it's solved.

Comment: For those who are very new to Ubuntu and just using copy-paste to install notepadqq like me... I did it using `sudo apt-get install pkg-config`

Answer (score 0):

The error is (almost) always at the end. In your case you're missing the header files from uchardet needed to compile notepadqq.

Depending on your distro, the package could be named `uchardet-dev`, `uchardet-devel`, `libuchardet-dev` or `libuchardet-devel`

Look at the home page (https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/uchardet/) for more info

Comment: Thank you for your response gengisdave. I am currently running kubuntu and at the time I posted this question I had already installed `libuchardet-dev` and `libuchardet0` packages that are needed for the notepadqq. However I didn't have installed `uchardet` package that you recommended I install. I did install it both from the apt-get package installer and from the official source from the website you mentioned. Nothing worked and I got the same result.